Storing Process Ids for transient processes on Windows strategy?
I have a low level application that that stores process IDs (PID) for running processes on Windows, such as those belonging to connhost or svchost for example. I gather these at the start of my application's runtime. However, such processes are transient and can be restarted with a different PID. Now my process Id does not belong to the correct process.
Let us suppose that polling my list of PIDs and checking their identity is too costly for my application. Is there a way that I can perform an event driven update of my PID list when one of these processes is killed?
Is there anything in the Win API that could be helpful here, such as a handle to the process?
